# Using Vector3.slerp

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine

I just want to know if I'm using vector3.slerp correctly as I have some issues.

I have set up a cube in a scene and I want it move smoothly from its current position to one being passed into by the program. Before I was trying to use the slerp I simply had my cube moving from its current point to its new point like this (as I said, the math all works):

```
cubeFour.transform.localPosition = new Vector3((B2*C1 - B1*C2)/delta,0,(A1*C2 - A2*C1)/delta);
```

But when I put it in a slerp call, my cube is no longer on the screen. This is how I'm calling it:

```
Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(lerpX, lerpY, lerpZ);

cubeFour.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Slerp(cubeFour.transform.localPosition, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime);
```

LerpX, LerpY & LerpZ are local variables I've set to contain the X, Y & Z of the first Vector3 I created in my first attempt.

Have I set up the slerp correctly or have I made a kerfuffle somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

[`Slerp`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html) is best for directions, [`Lerp`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) is best for positions. You should probably be using `Lerp`. And [`Time.deltaTime`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) is almost certainly the wrong choice for `t`. You should be giving it a number that moves from 0 to 1 over the time that you want the cube to move, e.g.

```
float moveTimeInSeconds = 2;
cubeFour.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(cubeStartingPosition, targetPosition, (Time.time - startTime) / moveTimeInSeconds);
```

Or use [`MoveTowards`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) if it makes more sense to define the speed of motion, and to move towards a target regardless of a starting point, instead of via starting and ending positions and times.

```
float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
cubeFour.transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(cubeFour.transform.localPosition, targetPosition, step);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried them both, however nothing appears on my screen still. When I just put in the first line of my post, it works fine. This is odd.

Answer (score 0):

**Lerp uses a percentage to animate!**

This means you must plug in a percentage, not a value near the same thing each frame.

Example Update():

```
var animationSpeedInSeconds=1;
var animationCounter:float=0;
function Update(){
    if(animationCounter>=0 && animationCounter<=1){
        animationCounter+=Time.deltaTime/animationSpeedInSeconds;
        cubeFour.transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(cubeFour.transform.localPosition, targetPosition, animationCounter);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!