# moving my object with transform.Translate make it move in wrong way

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine

I'm having a hard time with unity trying to translate a simple object. The object move in a 3 dimension world but only on the x and z axis. The function I'm using is the Translate function of my transform of my gameobject. x and z are the position I'm trying to move my object.

```
transform.Translate (( new Vector3(x - transform.position.x ,0,z - transform.position.z)).normalized * Time.deltaTime  * speed,Space.World);
```

So here's the problem I'm dealing with : If the result of my calcul is the following Vector : `(0,0,-1.0)`, my object move slowly in the wrong direction.

Example :

Starting position `(25.16, 1.0, 12.0)`
Final position after the translate function : `(25.6, 1.0, 12.1)`

Any help would be appeciate to help me understand this.

Comment: Just do this `.Translate( 3f*Time.deltaTime, 2f*Time.deltaTime, 2f*Time.deltaTime );`  You can also just put in the three arguments like that.  For Translate you tell it HOW MUCH TO MOVE, you DON'T put in again your current position. if you want to "JUST JUMP" somewhere, just set the position. `transform.position = new Vector3(5f ..`

Comment: Hmm, in my .Translate function, I use my transform.position to calculate the new vector that tell me how much i have to travel between my targetPos x and y and my object. I after normalized to get how much i ahve to move.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19821918/294884

Comment: Thanks Joe ! it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this script in one of my projects to move an GameObject to a point, just attach it on your game object and enter your x and y in FinPos.

```
using UnityEngine;

    public class MovementAnimation : MonoBehaviour
    {  
        public Vector3 FinPos;
        public bool Loop = true;
        public int Speed = 1;

        private Vector3 StartPos;
        private float startTime;
        private float lenght;

        void Start ()
        {
            StartPos = this.transform.position;
            startTime = Time.time;
            lenght = Vector3.Distance(StartPos, FinPos);
        }

        void Update ()
        {
            if (this.transform.position == FinPos)
            {
                if (Loop)
                {
                    this.transform.position = StartPos;
                    startTime = Time.time;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                float distance = (Time.time - startTime) * Speed;
                this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(StartPos, FinPos, distance / lenght);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is *usually* completely wrong. **You can't compare floats for equality.** In any real world project you cannot do this `this.transform.position == FinPos`.  However, it is true (check doco of `Vector3` operators) that Unity performs a poorly-documented `Mathf.Approximately` there, so it often "kind of works usually".