# Unity - Variable automatically changes back to its old value after it is changed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, properties, collision, pong

I have a problem with setting a property in a class from another class.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ProjectileBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
#region Variables
[SerializeField] private int _velocity;
private int _directionx = 1;
private int _directiony;
private bool _isHit;
private Rigidbody2D rb;

public int Velocity { get => _velocity; set => _velocity = value; }
public bool IsHit { get => _isHit; set => _isHit = value; }
public int Directionx { get => _directionx; set => _directionx = value; }
public int Directiony { get => _directiony; set => _directiony = value; }
#endregion

#region Game Loop
void Awake()
{
    Setup();
}

private void Update()
{

}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    MoveProjectile();
    Debug.Log(_directionx);
}
#endregion

#region Helper Functions
private void MoveProjectile() => transform.position += (-transform.right * (Time.deltaTime * Velocity)) * Directionx;

private void Setup()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    IsHit = false;
}
#endregion
}
```

This class describes the behaviour of a projectile I want to be shot at the beginning of the scene. The property DirectionX is responsible for the direction of the movement of the projectile. So if Directionx = 1, then the projectile should move to the left, if Directionx = -1, the projectile should move to the right. Now I want to change _directionx through another class.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
public ProjectileBehaviour projectileBehaviour;

void Start()
{
    
}

void Update()
{
    
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Projectile")) { ReflectProjectile(); }
}

private void ReflectProjectile()
{
    projectileBehaviour.Directionx = -1;
    Debug.Log(projectileBehaviour.Directionx);
}
}
```

This class is responsible for the collision of objects with the player. Now if Projectile with the tag "Projectile" hits the player, the directionx property is set to -1 which works fine. But there is a problem:
[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5SRk.png)
Even though directionx is set to -1 for a brief moment, it changes back to 1. Therefore the projectile is not being reflected and flies through the player.

Thank you for reading, any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: one simple issue is, it may be hitting the trigger twice (or more often).  simply add "Debug.Log("hello");
inside the OnTrigger code, and you will have your answer

Comment: note that there's absolutely no reason to use Properties up top there.  just use simple ordinary variables.

Comment: @Fattie I wouldn't ^^ properties are fine here. yes, currently they are redundant but it allows to later add cleaning for the setter parts without having to afterwards add properties ;) It also allows to debug these field directly in the Unity inspector - which doesn't work with properties - without having to make these fields puplic

Comment: @Fattie I followed your advice and added "Debug.Log("hello")" to the onTrigger code and it only triggers once. I used to use public variables but as derHugo explained I want my code to be cleaner, easier to understand and easier to maintain. I thought it shouldn't make a difference when actually running the code but somehow it does :l

Comment: simply use NonSerialized public variables. (that is to say "ordinary" public ordinary variables.  if you leave off the "NonSerialized" it becomes an "inspector" variable which you can change in the inspector, you don't want that in this case)

Comment: BTW generally never use FixedUpdate unless you are really expert. It has nothing to do with what you think, and you should not be using it in this case.  Time.deltaTime works specifically with Update.  Don't use FixedUpdate

Comment: BTW generally don't ever set the position in Unity.  Use Translate.  there are a number of reasons for this.  just use the first comment by me here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35232608/294884

Comment: @Fattie Yes I'm new to unity and c# but several Tutorials taught me to do physics calculations inside fixedUpdate while to Take Input preferably in Update. I probably have to Look Up Time.delatTime again. I went ahead and use translate now, thank you. It is tempting to Just use normal variables or non serialized ones, but I actually wonder why it doesn't work right now. If you have some ressources where i can Look that Up or If you could explain it, that would be very nice!

Comment: Hi @Moe.Mayati - allow me to repeat myself.  :) :)  DO NOT use FixedUpdate.  Hopefully that's pretty clear now  :) :)  You are facing two massive problems.  You see how you mention "physics".  ***You are not doing any physics here.***  At this point, you literally honestly *don't even know* what the PhysX system is in Unity!!!!  As I say, here and now, in the actual thing you are doing, completely delete FixedUpdate and use Update.  Nothing will work properly until you do that.  The second major problem U face is, a well-known crisis with Unity is that many of the tutorials, etc...

Comment: ... on the web are *utterly* incorrect (a sub problem is many are incredibly out of date).  Amazingly this even applies to Unity's own doco in many cases.  So it's really dangerous trying to learn unity online unfortunately.

Comment: just BTW as a rule (not always, but generally) you *never* Translate (or just move) a rigidbody .. simply set it's velocity and leave Unity to do it !!

Comment: @Fattie ok I gave up, I changed every variable to a public one. BUT! The variable will still not change! Is it cursed? I don't know what to do... could it be that something is messed up with unity or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one instance of your proyectile, you might be getting in the console the 1 direction of another's projectile fixed update:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    MoveProjectile();
    Debug.Log(_directionx);
}
```

You can check that out differenciating your log messages

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I'm pretty new to Unity and c#. I don't quite get why there would be more than one instance. There is only one gameobject of projectile when I start the scene, doesn't that mean there is only one instance of it?

Comment: it's really common that you accidentally do somthing, such as, accidentally put a script (either of them) in more than one place, etc.  you solve the problem on this page by basically adding Debugs everywhere.  a good trick is to include gameObject.name in the debug text, just to be sure

Comment: @Moe.Mayati, the class you define in your code is a template of an object. The code is the template of how that object constructs and behaves. That said, then you can have the object itself, that is what is called the instance (or many of them!). As a recipee to make a dish, and then the dish itself. When you have more than one object/instance, code runs for each of them. So I was suggesting that if you could be having more than one, the updated _directionx = 1 you could be seeing, could be of another instance/object. However if there is only one projectile as you say, it is not the case :)

Comment: @Moe.Mayati , I can't in your code see the specific problem you're having, but to find the root cause you will have to strip down your code and scene.  Totally and utterly eliminate the Properties and use trivial variables.  Eliminate FixedUpdate as I mention.  Put Debug.Log in EVERYWHERE, including the gameObject.name trick.  Be aware that its' common that (for some reason) you have more GameObjects than you think (you think there is only one tank, but there's another invisible one you forgot.)  It's common that you have accidentally put a component (script) somewhere and forgot about it.

Comment: try all these things and  You'll solve the mystery puzzle here !